# Error when trying to list all file in google storage key

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I wrote this method to list all files in a google storage bucket/key

```
def getObjectsAsList(keyName : String) = {
println("keyName " + keyName)
val blobs: Page[Blob] = storage.list(bucketName) //, Storage.BlobListOption.prefix(keyName)
println(blobs.getValues.asScala.toList.map(blob => blob.getName))
println()
println(blobs.getValues.asScala.toList.map(blob => blob.getName).tail)
blobs.getValues.asScala.toList.map(blob => bucketName + "/" + blob.getName).tail
```

}

When I call this from a key/bucket name, I am getting this error message

```
NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors.directExecutor()Ljava/util/concurrent/Executor;
at com.google.api.gax.retrying.BasicRetryingFuture.<init>(BasicRetryingFuture.java:88)
at com.google.api.gax.retrying.DirectRetryingExecutor.createFuture(DirectRetryingExecutor.java:88)
at com.google.api.gax.retrying.DirectRetryingExecutor.createFuture(DirectRetryingExecutor.java:74)
at com.google.cloud.RetryHelper.run(RetryHelper.java:75)
at com.google.cloud.RetryHelper.runWithRetries(RetryHelper.java:50)
at com.google.cloud.storage.StorageImpl.listBlobs(StorageImpl.java:452)
at com.google.cloud.storage.StorageImpl.list(StorageImpl.java:408)
at $linefd9088b4915a45cdbafa0cbf3f5f6cce27.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$GCPUtils.getObjectsAsList(command-2336709407006529:26)
at $linefd9088b4915a45cdbafa0cbf3f5f6cce27.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$GCPUtils.getObjectsAsList$(command-2336709407006529:24)
at $linefd9088b4915a45cdbafa0cbf3f5f6cce29.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$Test$.getObjectsAsList(command-1394774298623667:4)
at $linefd9088b4915a45cdbafa0cbf3f5f6cce29.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-1394774298623667:54)
at $linefd9088b4915a45cdbafa0cbf3f5f6cce29.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-1394774298623667:107)
at $linefd9088b4915a45cdbafa0cbf3f5f6cce29.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-1394774298623667:109)
at $linefd9088b4915a45cdbafa0cbf3f5f6cce29.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-1394774298623667:111)
at $linefd9088b4915a45cdbafa0cbf3f5f6cce29.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-1394774298623667:113)
at $linefd9088b4915a45cdbafa0cbf3f5f6cce29.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-1394774298623667:115)
at $linefd9088b4915a45cdbafa0cbf3f5f6cce29.$read$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-1394774298623667:117)
at $linefd9088b4915a45cdbafa0cbf3f5f6cce29.$read$$iw.<init>(command-1394774298623667:119)
```

This is the list of libraries I am suing

```
com.google.cloud:google-cloud-storage:1.113.14-sp.2
com.google.guava:guava:31.0.1-jre
```

Please let me know if I am making any mistakes here

Comment: Did you try to remove guava dependency?

Comment: Have you tried Guillaume's suggestion of removing the Guava dependency? Also can you follow [this document](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/listing-objects#storage-list-objects-java) and try to list the objects?